# ddlient returning 127.0.0.1 instead of external IP

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ddclient

I'm using ddclient on multiple machines without any problems (Ubuntu 12.04 & 14.04), but one machine randomly returns 127.0.0.1

I'm using the same configuration for all machines (except hostname naturally)

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

protocol=dyndns2
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com, web-skip='IP Address'
server=members.dyndns.org
login=***
password='***'
something.dyndns.org
```

I suspect something is amiss with the network configuration, but as I'm not in charge of the network and the guys in charge are no help, I'm trying to fix the problem on my end.

The following line from the help section:

```
  -if-skip pattern      : skip any IP addresses before 'pattern' in the output of ifconfig {if}.
```

seems to tell me I can skip certain addresses, but I don't understand how to use it, and what the 'web-skip' command I already use is for.

Executing 'ddclient -daemon=0 -query' returns the following:

```
use=if, if=br0 address is 192.168.12.3
use=if, if=eth0 address is NOT FOUND
use=if, if=eth1 address is NOT FOUND
use=if, if=eth2 address is NOT FOUND
use=if, if=eth3 address is NOT FOUND
use=if, if=lo address is 127.0.0.1
use=web, web=dnspark address is <correct external ip>
use=web, web=dyndns address is <correct external ip>
use=web, web=loopia address is <correct external ip>
```

Does ddclient return the 'lo' address for some reason, even though I want the web address? Is there a way to NOT send address updates if ddclient thinks it is 127.0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Now look at who is asking this question.  Hi Pit!

From what I understand you don't need to get any of the local interfaces, just the webservice based one.
I have one service left using dyndns.org (the rest I migrated to my own platform), and I'm in a similar situation.  web-skip is empty though. (Also it runs on OpenBSD and is a bit older version)

That's the only significant difference I see.  Here is my config (granted, as I said running on OpenBSD)

```
# grep -v ^# ddclient.conf | grep -v ^$
daemon=300                              # check every 300 seconds
syslog=yes                              # log update msgs to syslog
mail=root                               # mail all msgs to root
mail-failure=root                       # mail failed update msgs to root
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid               # record PID in file.
ssl=no                                  # use ssl-support.  Works with
                                        # ssl-library
                                        # new IP is added as argument.
use=web,                                \
web=ip.myownplatform.lu,                \
web-skip=''
login=user                              # default login
password=secret                         # default password
custom=yes,                             \
server=members.dyndns.org,              \
protocol=dyndns2                        \
jawtheshark.com
```

As you see, most of the other changes are irrelevant.  The only real difference I see is web-skip=''

Perhaps something to try?

Comment: Ah, never mind.  I remember what web-skip means.  It's the part of the text that needs to be dumped by the web service.
My webservice just gives the bare IP address.  (My service being http://ip.homesupport.lu).

I'm going to see what the output of checkip.dyndns.com is, in order to see whether the web-skip is correct.

Comment: checkip.dyndns.com outputs : `Current IP Address: 194.154.205.47`.  Try setting your web-skip to 'Current IP Address:`

Comment: ... on the other hand, it works on your other machines.  Peculiar.

Have you tried explicity telling it it should only regard web-obtained addresses?  `ddclient --help` tells me you should use the flag `-use=web` for that

Comment: Ugh, I realize that's useless too... That's basically what the config file contains.  Since it's random, have you investigated connection issues?  Is this machine, indeed able to connect to the outside at all times.

Even then, it shouldn't update to lo.  When mine fails to connect to the webservice, it sends me a mail and that's it.

Comment: This is an interesting read: https://sourceforge.net/p/ddclient/discussion/399428/thread/6ac161a6/
It might really be a case of the IP webservice actually returning 127.0.01.
It's an old post, so things might have changed.  Try using another IP webservice for a while and see whether that fixes it.  You can use mine, if you want, if you don't hammer it.

Comment: 1. It works on 40 machines with that exact configuration 2. The configuration already includes use=web 3. I found the sourceforge link myself, but it did not help 5. I'm currently thinking about a selfhosted solution, but need this fixed asap. Don't want to use another service. 6. Hi there :)

Comment: You don't need to switch from DynDNS.  Just use a different ip address webservice (the one that echos your IP).  The update still goes to DynDNS.  I'd do that to exclude issues caused by their webservice.

I would really monitor eventual connection issues.

Comment: Basically, you need to figure out what exactly is different between this machine and the 40 other ones.  Since you are using DynDNS, we know with a relatively big certainty that they're on different network.  Most probably cause: the network.

Comment: You do need to read: "I'm not in charge of the network and the guys in charge are no help". But yes different network for each machine

Comment: I read that... But that doesn't change that the problem most likely resides there.  Sometimes a reply you don't want to hear is still the correct reply.